# Multiple checkboxes with Ajax strange behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a form with many checkboxes, and a PHP page is called for updating the database on each click.

HTML

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="status1" id="event_status1" value="1" >
   <input type="checkbox" name="status2" id="event_status2" value="1" >
   <input type="checkbox" name="status3" id="event_status3" value="1" >
</form>
```

JQuery

```
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var isChecked = $("input:checkbox").is(":checked") ? 1:0; 
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "admin-ajax.php",
           data: { event_status:$("input:checkbox").attr("id"), status:isChecked},
           success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
           }
     });        
  });
```

It works well when I check/uncheck each checkbox individualy.

If I check the 3 boxes, the last I have checked won't send "0" status if I uncheck it but wil always send "1".

Comment: Your problem is in the "isChecked" variable. You want to check for $(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `input` dom whose change event is triggered not this one

```
$("input:checkbox")
```

You have to do something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    var isChecked = self.is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
    $.ajax({
        type:    'POST',
        url:     "admin-ajax.php",
        data:    {event_status: self.attr("id"), status: isChecked},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

---

If you want to prepare the ajax `data` object outside of `$.ajax` you can do like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {event_status: $(this).attr("id"), status: +$(this).is(":checked")};
    $.ajax({
        type:    'POST',
        url:     "admin-ajax.php",
        data:    data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: `+` in `+$(this).is(":checked")` converts boolean to Number, `false` becomes 0, and `true` becomes 1

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with third line:

```
 var isChecked = $("input:checkbox").is(":checked") ? 1:0;
```

You use jquery selector `$('input:checkbox')` which will return random checkbox from whole HTML DOM Structure, this will not return your clicked Checkbox, So the solution is use `this`.

So the code will look like this:

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1:0; 
     var eleId = $("this").attr("id");
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: "admin-ajax.php",
           data: { event_status:eleId, status:isChecked},
           success: function (response) {
              console.log(response);
           }
     });        
  });
```

Comment: `$("this").attr("id")` syntax error, and we cannot access outer `$(this)`, from inside `$.ajax` using `$(this)`.

Comment: @Rajan, thanks to correct me, Actually i was giving the basic idea behind the problem. BTW Thanks to correct me